# UIAlertView if CCMenuItemFont (text) tapped

Tags: iphone, text, cocos2d-iphone, uialertview

I'm using cocos2d, and I want a UIAlertView to pop up IF text of a CCMenuItemFont is tapped. I can get the alertView to pop up, but I want it AFTER that text is tapped. Here's my code
**INIT**

```
    rate = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Rate App" target:self selector:@selector(rateIsTapped:clickedButtonAtIndex:)];
    rate.position = ccp(240, 160);
    [self addChild:rate];



-(void)rateTapped:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {    
rateView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like This App?" message:@"Rate it on the App Store!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Sure, I'll rate it!", nil];
[rateView show];
[rateView autorelease];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"rate"]; 

if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    //[alertView collapse];
}
if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"LINK TO RATE IN APP STORE"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is wrong.. It should not be show alert and tapped together.. And you have to add the menuitemFont to a CCMenu..

```
rate = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Rate App" target:self selector:@selector(rateApp)];

CCMenu* menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:rate, nil];
    menu.position = CGPointMake(-(size.width / 2), size.height / 2);
    menu.tag = 100;
    [self addChild:menu];


-(void)rateApp
{
rateView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Like This App?" message:@"Rate it on the App Store!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No thanks" otherButtonTitles:@"Sure, I'll rate it!", nil];
[rateView show];
[rateView release];
[defaults setBool:Yes forKey:@"rate"];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
{
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
//[alertView collapse];
}

if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"LINK TO RATE IN APP STORE"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but still it's not doing anything when I click on Rate App on the simulator. But there's no crash

Comment: And yes, I changed it to be 2 methods, and the selector is the 1st method (rate)

Comment: NSLog at the rate app function.. did it run the function??

Comment: Hmm.. i have edited the codes.. my bad.. didnt realise that you didnt add it to CCMenu.. I have added the codes.. Take a look at it again..

Comment: Thanks! Didn't notice that ;)